# Does 'a graph is a DAG $\iff$ there exists a topological sorting' hold for graphs with a non-finite number of nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice, sorting

Does 'a graph is a DAG $\iff$ there exists a topological sorting' hold for graphs with a non-finite number of nodes?

I see this statement at a lot of places e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). However it is not specified whether the graphs are finite.

The accompanying definitions are:
DAG = directed and acyclic. 
A topological sorting is a linear ordering of the nodes such that for each edge $uv$, the node $u$ comes before $v$ in the ordering.

Could the answer be a related to the axiom of choice?

According to [wiki: partial orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).
Every strict partial order is a DAG. And the transitive closure of a DAG is a DAG and a strict partial order. (Which might help in the connection with choice)

Comment: If I understand it correctly, looking at a DAG as a relation, then its transitive closure is a partial order. And a topological sorting is a linear extension of that order.

Comment: Well, there is indeed a well-defined relationship $>$ that is transitive: $u>v$ iff there exists a dipath from $u$ to $v$ in $G$. However, *answering the query* "given $u$ and $v$, do $u$ and $v$ satisfy the relation $u>v$?" seems harder, I believe that you can do it in finite time but I am not positive.

Comment: Do you have a specific infinite graph in mind or is this in general?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila, I think you are right.

Comment: @Mike, I had no specific graph in mind. But if it turns out to be a difficult problem I would start with a countable graph first.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on the site about extension of partial orders to linear orders with and without the axiom of choice.