# Equivalence between directed acyclic graph and topological ordering

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a directed graph. I learned that if $G$ has finitely many vertices, then it is a directed acyclic graph if and only if it has a topological order. I think sufficiency is still true for $G$ with inifinitely many vertices: if $G$ has a topological order, then $G$ is a DAG. But I am wondering whether necessity is also true for the infinite case.

For the finite case, the proof of necessity usually starts showing that there is at least one vertex which has no incoming edge: every path has finite length and there are finitely many paths; pick an arbitrary path among the longest paths; the starting vertex has no incoming edge. Clearly, this argument relies on finiteness of $G$. I know that this claim is no longer true if there are infinitely many vertices, as the example $G = (V, E)$ where $V = \mathbb{Z}$ and $E = \{(n+1, n)|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ shows. But even in this example, the usual $>$ order is a topological order of $G$. So I am wondering whether DAG still implies the existence of topological order when $G$ is infinite.

Thank you very much for any hint or reference.

Comment: This question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177976/does-a-graph-is-a-dag-iff-there-exists-a-topological-sorting-hold-for-graph) but remains unanswered. Perhaps the comments there may be helpful.

Comment: I think you can do this for a countable dag : Fix an arbitrary ordering for the vertices. For each vertex in order, we label it with a real by ensuring that $l(u) < l(v) \iff$ there is no path from $v$ to $u$. For each new vertex $v$, we choose a label between $\max\{l(u) |$ there is a path from $u$ to $v$ $\}$ and $\min\{l(u) |$ there is a path from $v$ to $u$ $\}$. If the $\max$ is greater than $\min$, we have a contradiction, if the $\max$ is equal to the $\min$, we have a loop.